# meson doesn't find binary dependency

Tags: meson-build

I compiled wayland from source code with this command

```
meson --buildtype=release -D prefix=$HOME/mylib -D documentation=false
```

then installed it with `ninja`. Now in `$HOME/mylib` I have this structure:

```
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x  6 myuser myuser 4.0K Dec  3 19:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 myuser myuser 4.0K Dec  4 17:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root             root             4.0K Dec  3 19:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root             root             4.0K Dec  3 19:52 include
drwxr-xr-x  3 root             root             4.0K Dec  3 19:52 lib
drwxr-xr-x  4 root             root             4.0K Dec  3 19:52 share
```

Inside *bin* folder I have `wayland-scanner` and when I run this command

```
wayland-scanner -v
```

I got this output:

```
wayland-scanner 1.21.90
```

Now when I build other source code with `meson` that has wayland-scanner as dependency I got this error:

```
../tests/meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'wayland-scanner' ['>=1.20.0'] found '1.18.0'.
```

This is related to another `wayland-scanner` that is placed here:

```
/usr/bin/wayland-scanner
```

with version 1.18.0. The command

```
echo $PATH
```

reply with this output:

```
/home/myuser/mylib/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Why meson doesn't find the updated version of wayland-scanner? Using `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` doesn't work, same error as above

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, during another build, wailand-scanner (even it's executable binary) is searched with the help of pkg-config tool (the standard way for meson to search dependencies). So, check where wayland-scanner.pc is installed, it should be */home/myuser/mylib/share/pkgconfig/wayland-scanner.pc*
Then, before running a build, try updating PKG_CONFIG_PATH

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PAT=/home/myuser/mylib/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi don't know the wayland package, but from description
I could think that /usr/bin/wayland-scanner is a link to the old installation,
Try to look in your environment for the wayland-scanner scanner binary to check if there is some link do not updated to the new installation.